# How to copy trace files from Raspberry Pi to Ubuntu laptop?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, raspberry-pi, trace, scp

When I enable a tracing event (eg kmem) and try and copy the trace file from /sys/kernel/debug/tracing on my Raspberry Pi to my Ubuntu laptop using `scp`, the tracefile comes to my laptop as an empty file. When I copy a file from my home directory on the RasPi to my laptop with the same `scp` command, it works.

I have tried changing the permissions of the /sys/kernel/debug/tracing directory using `chmod o+rwx .` but this makes no difference. I have also tried copying the trace file into the ~ directory on my RasPi, but this takes too long to copy over.
I'm not sure why the trace file is coming as an empty file even after I apply chmod to the directory, maybe `scp` doesn't work for trace files or something?